# Python program stops unexpectedy

Tags: python, python-3.x

The programm is about hash cracker in python. It basically goes through a huge list of passwords and then makes the md5 hash of each one and compares it to my hash. It works perfectly, unless I put a password which is over line 4750 in the passlist. It stops there, the program ends, and I dont know why.

Here is my code

```
import os
try:
    import hashlib
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    os.system('pip3 install hashlib')
    import hashlib

def test_hash(target, string):
    hashed = hashlib.md5(string.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    if target == hashed:
        print(f'Found coincidence at -> {string}')
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
target_hash = 'an-md5-hash'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('passwordlist.txt', 'r') as file:
        count = 1
        while (line := file.readline().rstrip()):
            print(f'Trying passord {count} -> {line}')
            count += 1
            result = test_hash(target_hash, line)
            if result == 1:
                break
            else:
                continue
```

Comment: There's not a blank line in the file at line 4750 is there?

Comment: Oh it was that thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong in the file, possibly a wrong line format. I suggest you check the file at the line where the error occurs.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.